# Dynamically adding routes and components in Mithril

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

Mithril's website states:

> You can only have one m.route call per application.

So I was almost able to do a work around with [code splitting](https://mithril.js.org/route.html#code-splitting).

But my application is only aware of the first-level components for a given URL which it utilizes the async [code splitting](https://mithril.js.org/route.html#code-splitting) to accomplish.

Now the problem: *Those first-level components would then like to register their own namespaced routes to leverage URL state change for their own inner components* since I can't register their routes ahead of time (and Mithril prevents setting the routes again after the initial route was set by the app/wrapping component).

To further the complexity of the issue, each first level component is loaded on an as-needed basis, so I can't wait for *all* the first level components to load and then instantiate the m.route; routes have to be added dynamically.

I love this framework, but my use case seems like an edge case that I can't seem to resolve.

The simple solution would be to re-instantiate the m.route object after each first-level component loads, but that's not supported.

**UPDATE**

The purpose of my post was to find a native way to do dynamic routing and not lose functionality (such as variadic routing), but its been reinforced that that's not possible.

I replaced the entire router with an in-house one so I could support dynamic (and unknown) routes, more flexible variadic routing, better params method, and even provide get/set global data across views without a global window variable or use of the History API in that case. I still provide the rest of the functionality that Mithril does, just a little more simply.

Why not do a pull request? From what I've read on different Github pages, two big pieces of this would not work with the core logic of Mithril; and/or, is too much of an edge-case that they don't want to support it.

I'll still choose Mithril over any other framework though.

In the meantime, I built what I need, and hope Mithril 2 will have dynamic routing baked in.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a workaround using [params](https://mithril.js.org/route.html#mrouteparam)? Could work if you only need to support a limited number of slashes in the url, although it might become a bit messy.

Comment: @AmeHugo Yeah, I've written my own router a couple times over, but I was really hoping to not step outside Mithril for something it does so well in most areas.

Answer (score 1):

Mithril's router is intended as a relatively simple solution to easily enable standing up simple SPAs, dynamically registering routes isn't part of the current design.

I think you'll probably be best served by finding a router that supports the dynamic route registration you require and using that.

Integration of that router with Mithril could be naive (using `m.mount()` when routes change) or more complex by emulating a bit of the logic of the [existing router API](https://github.com/MithrilJS/mithril.js/blob/next/api/router.js#L14-L21).

Comment: Yeah, those are both alternatives and what I've already done in the meantime, but I really don't like to step out of Mithril when the built-in routing works well for most everything else. I was just hoping someone has run into this and found a good Mithril-centric solution.

Answer (score 1):

Mithril's router is not the most advanced tool. Although you can work around it pretty much however you want.

There is a way to make new routes dynamic. 
I made a little jsfiddle a while ago. https://jsfiddle.net/Godje/cpzLtoyz/

You are interested in lines 2-11 and 63-92.

Although they aren't dynamic in the fiddle, you can make a function, to replace that `switch` on line 73, which will process your routes and return a component needed to be rendered. That way if you have an array stream with all the URLs or other routes you want, you can have a function process each `param` on each route-change call and check it with the array.

Sorry for a messy response. Writing an exact solution to the problem requires a local server.

Comment: I built a replacement router last year, with the base concept similar to what @Tivac and you suggested. I like how you stuck with built-in methods to get some of the other data needed. The downside is losing the variadic routing, but nice work.